# How to force cpanm to use HTTPS insted of Using HTTP for installing dependencies

Tags: perl, cpanm

Hi I am trying to install perl modules using cpanm.But my firewall is not letting the cpanm to use http.
Even when I am forcing it to use https using the --mirror option, its still uses http to install the dependencies. How can i force cpanm to use only https://mirror-address .

```
Perl Version 5.16.3
Cpanm Version 1.6922
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/App-cpanminus/bin/cpanm):

> ```
> cpanm --from https://cpan.metacpan.org/ Plack    # use only the HTTPS mirror
> ```

Comment: Hi @Steffen Ullrich . This method requires LWP::Protocol::https .Due to my firewall  I can't install it through cpanm

Comment: @xaglez: Then maybe you should get a Perl which has this already installed? There is nothing known about your system but on Windows there is strawberry Perl which includes all of this and on the various Linux distributions the necessary modules are also prepackaged and available through apt or rpm. Of course you can also download all of these modules with the browser and install these then locally.

Comment: @xaglez You can pass the --no-lwp option to force cpanm to use curl or wget which should be able to handle https.

Comment: HI @Steffen Ullrich  i am using RHEL 7.7 Docker container

Comment: @xaglez: there is an rpm for perl-LWP-Protocol-https

Comment: @xaglez, Feel free to download [LWP-Protocol-https](https://metacpan.org/release/LWP-Protocol-https) by some other means

Answer (score 0):

If you use Linux or Unix, try:

```
~$ echo "alias cpanm='cpanm --from https://cpan.metacpan.org/'" >> .bashrc
~$ source .bashrc
```